# Php include within .tpl file of type pararaphs field

Tags: php, drupal-7, include, drupal-theming, paragraphs

As I understand you got to use the template.php for including files within specific .tpl files.

```
<?php print theme('your_shared_template_file', $args); ?>
```

The problem is just that the hook_preprocess_field function is not called for any paragraph field. Also the hook_field function does not seem to be called by a paragraph field.

So as the include statement is ignored - how do I embed another php into a paragraphs field tpl file?

Thanks